# Ryu combos sometimes not registering

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've had Ryu for about a week, and I've been trying to input his original inputs from Street Fighter without much success. I clearly see my circle pad go in a 180 degree circle, yet no Shankunetsu Hadoken. This especially applies to the true inputted Shoryuken, which may just be my lack of skill in this area.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or a more optimal circle pad movement that the game still recognizes as a true input?

Comment: They all work fairly consistently for me with some practice. They're just finicky

Comment: Yes they are just very finicky to get working. Other than practice, I'm not sure there's anything you can do. Perhaps controller choice might impact on it a bit.

Comment: Most likely, your input of the motion is a tad too slow; with some practice, these moves can easily be performed at will 100% of the time.

Comment: Well RIP I've half given up trying to input the Shoryuken. I guess that's why Trela is a pro...

Comment: @LeaguePastry I find no trouble with it at all! Are you hitting b after dragging it fast?

Comment: @Doorhandle I usually press A so that way they don't get a free punish off of my unintentional focus

Comment: @LeaguePastry Me too, but some people always get some sort of neutral b, that way what they intend to do almost always happens

Answer (score 1):

This is simply you not inputting the inputs correctly. They may be hard to do but there are some alternatives. Firstly, press (on a gamecube controller) press A instead of B, so if you screw up the input a shorter attack comes out instead of your non-true special.

As for alternatives to the inputs. You can use 2 quarter circles instead of a Z to get true shoryuken, and for true Hurricane Kick, try using a backwards half circle instead of backwards quarter circle to ensure you get the full quarter circle motion.

Comment: 2 quarter circles on what parts of the controller? If you tell me that, I'll accept this as an answer.